# Click To Dial fails after calling publish() in publisher.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, publisher, cti

Calling `publish(<message>)` in the publisher.js API with any valid message/data causes Click To Dial to stop working until any sforce.interaction function is called (ie. `sforce.interaction.isInConsole()`).

For example:

`function alertOnClickToDial (eventData) {
    alert("ClickToDial on number " + JSON.parse(eventData.result).number);
}

sforce.interaction.cti.onClickToDial(alertOnClickToDial);`

results in this:
[image: Alert]

This works until publish() is called:

`Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.customActionMessage", payload: {actionName: "CustomActionName", message: "ClickToDial"}});`

The alert stops appearing.

Debugging shows that the callback function is never executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to the data in the MessageEvent being sent by the Salesforce InteractionFramework.

The data in a successful MessageEvent should look something like this:

`interactionApi/?method=onClickToDial&<some data about the record/phone number>`

which indicates the message is for the interaction api and the method is onClickToDial (along with some data about the record/number clicked on).

After calling publish the data now looks like this:

`?method=onClickToDial&<some data about the record/phone number>`

the "interactionApi/" prefix is missing.

### interaction.js:

When you look at interaction.js it's clear why this is a problem.

```
function processPostMessage(event) {
    // Check if call is for entity feed
    if (isApiMessage(event, ENTITY_FEED_API)) {
        if (entityFeedApi && entityFeedApi.processPostMessage) {
            params = entityFeedApi.processPostMessage(event);
        }
        if (!params) {
            return;
        }
    } else if (isApiMessage(event, INTERACTION_API)) {
        if (event.origin !== frameOrigin || !frameOrigin) {
            // Only trust messages from the adapter frame
            return;
        }

        var message = event.data.replace(INTERACTION_API, ''); // strip off API target
        params = parseUrlQueryString(message);

        // convert string true/false to boolean for methods that needs to return boolean values.
        if (params && (params.result === 'true' || params.result === 'false')) {
            params.result = params.result === 'true';
        }
    } else {
        // return if postMessage is not targeted to interaction API
        return;
    }
}
```

In particular

`else if (isApiMessage(event, INTERACTION_API))`

prevents the API from responding to messages that were not directed to it, which seems very sensible, but this means the second onClickToDial call is ignored.

### InteractionFramework.js (auto-formatted in Chrome Dev Tools):

The culprit is in InteractionFramework.js.

```
a.INTERACTION_API = "interactionApi/";
a.isVersion25 = !1; //false

...

a.processPostMessage = function(b) {
    var c, e, d;
    try {
        if (b.origin.toLowerCase() !== a.sofphoneEventOriginUrl)
            a.doPostMessage(null , null , LC.getLabel("InteractionApi", "InvalidSoftphoneIframeOrigin"));
        else if (c = b.data || "",
        !(0 === c.indexOf(a.INTEGRATION_API) || 0 === c.indexOf(a.ENTITY_FEED_API)))
            if (0 === c.indexOf(a.INTERACTION_API) ? (c = c.replace(a.INTERACTION_API, ""),
            a.isVersion25 = !1) : a.isVersion25 = !0,

...

a.doPostMessage = function(b, c, e) {
    b = Sfdc.Url.generateQueryString("", {
        method: b,
        result: c,
        error: e
    });
    b = (a.isVersion25 ? "" : a.INTERACTION_API) + b;
    g ? Sfdc.support.servicedesk.PopoutWindowManager.sendMessage(g, "ProcessApiCallback", {
        postMessageData: b,
        iframeProxyData: null 
    }) : a.softphoneEventSource && a.softphoneEventSource.postMessage(b, a.sofphoneEventOriginUrl)
};
```

Which reads better like this:

```
a.isVersion25 = false;

...

// function processPostMessage()
if (0 === messageData.indexOf("interactionApi/")){
    messageData = messageData.replace("interactionApi/", "");
    a.isVersion25 = false;
}
else{
    a.isVersion25 = true;
}

...

// function doPostMessage()
messageData = (a.isVersion25 ? "" : a.INTERACTION_API) + messageData;
```

`a.isVersion25` is initialised to false, but is set every time a message is processed.
If the message data starts with "interactionApi/" then it is stripped and isVersion25 is set to false. The boolean value is then examined in `doPostMessage` and "interactionApi/" is added to the start again.

When calling the publish method another message is sent with data that looks like this:

```
{
    "seq":2,
    "src":"client",
    "clientVersion":"35.0",
    "body":{
        "type":"publish",
        "config":{
            "client:{
                "isVF":true,
                "oauthToken":"null",
                "instanceId":"SoftphoneIframe",
                "targetOrigin":"*"
            }
        },
        "event":{
            "name":"publisher.customActionMessage",
            "payload":{
                "actionName":"CustomActionName",
                "message":"ClickToDial"
            }
        }
    },
    "targetModule":"Canvas"
}
```

This JSON object does not start with "interactionApi/" so `a.isVersion25` is set to true. After this a Click To Dial will call into `doPostMessage` and find the value of `a.isVersion25` is true, so leave the message data untouched.

### Workaround

It's not very nice, but you can call any sforce.interaction function (such as isInConsole or isVisible) to reset it to a working state as these cause messages starting with "interactionApi/" to be sent.